# поиск по имени Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

У меня есть компонент внутри которого хранятся некоторые услуги (их 5 и у них есть только свойство их имени)
Мне нужно реализовать поиск так, чтобы как только мы бы вводили какую либо букву с клавиатуры, то программа проходилась бы по всем элементам и находила в каких есть эта бука, и выводила бы их все на экран (ну и так далее)

Comment: И нам тут что сделать? Написать тебе код?

Comment: Я сразу извиняюсь если пишу глупости или мало инфы, так как опыта у меня маловато, я отчасти говоря совсем не понимаю, как происходит этот процесс, хотя везде пишкт что такая фильтрация - очень легко

Comment: @АнтонКравцов u_mulder очень рогатый, уже не первый раз убеждаюсь. По хорошему, привести пример, что Вы пробовали и что не получается, и какие есть идеи как сделать

Comment: В том то и дело что я ничего не пробовал, потому что не знаю как и что делать, видел что есть какоето свойство CBlock которое вроде бы всю информацию достает из блока и может фильтровать, но мне то по сути нужно просто имя блока а дальше проверять есть ли введенные мною символы в имени этого инфоблока

Comment: такое не делал, но первая идея, возможно не очень оптимальная, после ввода буквы (или пробела или с задержкой что бы часто не делалось) js делаете ajax запрос на скрипт который делает поиск (можно стандартное использовать серч компонент) и возвращать список вариантов. То что вы хотите называется вывод поисковых подсказок при поиске попробуйте погуглить. Ещё можно взять компонент search.page и покопать в сторону его параметра USE_SUGGEST.